# Get the average mean of entries per month with datetime in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large df with many entries per month. I would like to see the average entries per month as to see as an example if there are any months that normally have more entries. (Ideally I'd like to plot this with a line of the over all mean to compare with but that is maybe a later question).
My df is something like this:

```
ufo=pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/pandas-videos/master/data/ufo.csv')
ufo['Time']=pd.to_datetime(ufo.Time)
```

Where the head looks like this: 
[image]

So if I'd like to see if there are more ufo-sightings in the summer as an example, how would I go about?

I have tried:

```
ufo.groupby(ufo.Time.month).mean()
```

But it does only work if I am calculating a numerical value. If I use `count()`instead I get the sum of all entries for all months.

EDIT: To clarify, I would like to have the mean of entries - ufo-sightings - per month.

Comment: `ufo.groupby(ufo.Time.month).size()`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. For example, let's take January 1930. What do you mean by 'average entries' in this month? How would you calculate it by hand?

Comment: @pmarcol by hand I would count all the entries of January and then divide by the number of "januaries" there are from the start of the df until the last entry of the df. And then with each month.

Comment: @QuangHoang then I still get the sum of all entries for each month. Is there a way to find how many of each month is present? i. e. from first to last entry how many jan, feb etc are there? and then divide the series I get from your command with that?

Comment: You should put your clarification above in the question.

Comment: @Mactilda ah, I see now. Then I would definitely suggest extracting month, and calculate count with group by, grouping by extracted month. Then the average can be calculated by dividing by total number of particular months in total timespan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this what you are looking for, still please ask for clarification if i didn't reached what you are looking for.

```
# Add a new column instance, this adds a value to each instance of ufo sighting
ufo['instance'] = 1

# set index to time, this makes df a time series df and then you can apply pandas time series functions.  
ufo.set_index(ufo['Time'], drop=True, inplace=True)   

# create another df by resampling the original df and counting the instance column by Month ('M' is resample by month)
ufo2 = pd.DataFrame(ufo['instance'].resample('M').count())

# just to find month of resampled observation
ufo2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(ufo2.index.values)

ufo2['month'] = ufo2['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
```

and finally you can groupby month :)

```
ufo2.groupby(by='month').mean()
```

and this is the output which looks like this:

```
month   mean_instance
1       12.314286
2       11.671429
3       15.657143
4       14.928571
5       16.685714
6       43.084507
7       33.028169
8       27.436620
9       23.028169
10      24.267606
11      21.253521
12      14.563380
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
# count the total months in the records
def total_month(x):
    return x.max().year -x.min().year + 1

new_df = ufo.groupby(ufo.Time.dt.month).Time.agg(['size', total_month])

new_df['mean_count'] = new_df['size'] /new_df['total_month']
```

Output:

```
    size    total_month     mean_count
Time            
1   862     57              15.122807
2   817     70              11.671429
3   1096    55              19.927273
4   1045    68              15.367647
5   1168    53              22.037736
6   3059    71              43.084507
7   2345    65              36.076923
8   1948    64              30.437500
9   1635    67              24.402985
10  1723    65              26.507692
11  1509    50              30.180000
12  1034    56              18.464286
```

Comment: Yes, This is what I was looking for. I am wondering if one shouldn't include all months even though there were no sightings so to speak to get a statistically correct material. Since there are 57 of January and 70 of February one would think that they wouldn't diff more than one. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I think it would be a valid point. Average count over the 71 years of records makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to group your data by month? I think we can do this

```
ufo['month'] = ufo['Time'].apply(lambda t: t.month)
ufo['year'] = ufo['Time'].apply(lambda t: t.year)
```

In this way, you will have 'year' and 'month' to group your data.

```
ufo_2 = ufo.groupby(['year', 'month'])['place_holder'].mean()
```

Comment: What is 'place_holder'? What does it do?

Comment: It means that I applied mean() to a column named 'palce_holder' which doesn't exist in your dataset.

Therefore, you can count 'month' and create a new column called 'month_count'. Then you should get your desired results.